# WAMP servers... why just for web development

Tags: wamp

What is to stop you using a WAMP server (or similar) to run single-user business database applications day-to-day?

I read everywhere that WAMP and the like are intended for the development of web apps, but why can't they be used to deploy desktop apps - what're the downsides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think WAMP/MAMP/LAMP are great applications that CAN be used for production servers.

I have started doing this myself as I do not have the complete knowledge in server administration on the linux end and my PHP applications are not compatible with IIS.

If you are a small operation than it should save you time then go for it.
If your business grows and you can afford to put on staff to manage dedicated servers with the Apache, PHP ect all installed separately then I also recommend this.

The main difference I can see is that WAMP probably wont be as scalable as the preferred setup. The binaries are all integrated and sometimes I have had issues trying to figure out which `php.ini` file the system is using.

WAMP is just as secure as any other server as long as you know how to do so, is provides a UI layer which cost CPU time but like I said if you are only serving small web sites/apps than this should be just fine.

My other recommendation is to install it on a Server (Windows 2008 RS or 20012) Windows servers are more reliable and powerful than the Windows User version. Just remember to turn off IIS and any other roles not used by the Windows Server.

Make sure you your WAMP folder backed up regularly!

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found one yet. I guess the speed won't be as good as a 'pure' setup, but it sounds like that isn't an issue.

I run an epos web app for a photo studio no problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

Actually i used with wamp for many purposes; I used it with VB.NET apps, PHP, etc...but I think if you want to use it for deployment, you should start by configuring it to do so.

For example, for PHP deactivation errors display in php.ini, start listening on all `allow all` in httpd.conf, activating safe mode, setting a password for MySQL; and many other options that have to be configured.

I personally prefer because it is a quick and lightweight tool.

Comment: Read the Synthetica License for the details of your previous problem. It specifically states that you may not alter the look and feel. All of the "free" L&F have the disclaimer in the GUI's that use them, and based on the license that you agree to when you download the software, you're stuck. Since our previous discussion, I have downloaded several of their L&F, and their appearances are nice, but all appear to come with disclaimer display which is likely part of the standard Synthetica Look and Feel.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP usually stands for Windows, Apache, Mysql, PHP or whatever your particular choice for P is.  It describes a stack meant for specifically for deploying/developing web applications and is a rough equivalent to LAMP.  Most things that would be considered desktop applications wouldn't use a webserver and more than likely would not be written in PHP.

The issue is not so much one of downsides as it is Apples and Oranges: Desktop applications are usually built with a less web centric stack.

Comment: I understand what WAMP/LAMP/MAMP is, but I'm just curious as to why stuff that gets developed using these tools seems to be branded "for development", and never "for final use". Because, from what I can see this approach seems like a quick way to develop simple cross-platform business applications, where all the end user has to do is install WAMP/LAMP/MAMP first, and also have a browser.